# Testing for HTTP TRACE method

Tags: web-application, appsec, penetration-test, http, apache

**How can I test for HTTP TRACE on my web-server?**

I need to train a Tester how to verify that the HTTP TRACE method is disabled.

Ideally I need a script to paste into Firebug to initiate a https connection to return the web server response to a HTTP TRACE command.

**Background:**

Our security Pen Testers identified a HTTP TRACE vulerability and we need to prove that it is fixed.

**References:**

- [OWASP on XST](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Methods_and_XST_%28OWASP-CM-008%29)
- [Apache Week](http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/03-01-24#news)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (which is scriptable).

```
 curl -v -X TRACE http://www.yourserver.com
```

Running it against an Apache server with `TraceEnable Off` correctly returns `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed` (just tested on an Apache 2.2.22)

This also works on HTTPS sites, provided that cURL has the correct information supplied to the SSL layer. This is the lazy man's check of Google

```
curl --insecure -v -X TRACE https://www.google.com/
```

...it negotiates the connection (does not verify the certificate chain, but that's not the issue here since we want to check on `TRACE` status), and responds 405:

```
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=www.google.com
*        start date: 2013-02-20 13:34:56 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-06-07 19:43:27 GMT
*        subjectAltName: www.google.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.25.0 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.25.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.0
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: While probably being the simplest solution over plain HTTP, this doesn't work over HTTPS.

Comment: I've tried with Google (trace disabled) and another server (trace enabled) and it seems to work to me. Updating answer...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers, but this answer was the most user friendly of the lot.

Comment: I was getting **Empty reply from server** when running this remotely. SSHing into the server and doing `curl -v -X TRACE http://127.0.0.1` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways:

STEP 1: `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443`

STEP2 :

```
TRACE / HTTP/1.1
host: example.com
```

(press enter twice)

or

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
host: example.com
```

(press enter twice) 
(you might need to paste these rapidly so copy paste them rather by typing out)
STEP 3: Verify if the output, it should give error 400 if I'm not mistaking.

Another tool you can use is gnutls.

Comment: If they aren't using HTTPS, you can replace your step 1 (`openssl s_client -connect example.com:443`) with `telnet example.com 80`.

Comment: On Unix these send LF for line terminator not CRLF as specified by 1945/2068/2616/7230 and _might_ be rejected, ignored, or handled differently by a server; to be safe use `s_client` with `-crlf` or redirect the input from a file created with `unix2dos` or ctl-V ctl-M or equivalents, or a pipeline that uses e.g. `printf '%s\r\n' "GET / HTTP/1.1" "Host: whatever" ""`

Answer (score 5):

You could use a **proxy**, like [Burp Suite](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/) or [Zap](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/), and follow some simple steps:

1. set up your browser to pass through the chosen proxy;
2. make a normal HTTP request (e.g. `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`) and intercept it;
3. change the HTTP method to TRACE and send the request to the server;
4. check the HTTP response.

If the response includes the whole request, then TRACE is enabled and working properly.

Answer (score 4):

What everyone else said was accurate as far as sending the test however no one has given a correct identification for whether it's vulnerable.  Different servers will respond differently, not to mention any mod rewrites on a TRACE/TRACK request.  There are two ways of identifying both the TRACE and TRACK vulnerabilities which seem to work without giving false positives or false negatives (that i've been made aware of).

1) The target returns any status code < 400 or >= 600

2) The target returns the headers which you passed in.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using `netcat`

```
nc www.myhost.com 80
TRACE /mypage.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myhost.com
```

An example of output is

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=rfyji7QBFFld7HwMGLVM+F8s.undefined; Path=/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1125
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 06:06:29 GMT
```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate all the great answers provided by the skilled users of the website. I saw your questions reference and you mentioned about `OWASP`. I'm considering you are familar with the use of owasp and esp owasp live cd.

. The tool has a http request field actually its more then a field its allow the custom generation of entire http header. You can select `trace` define the header options and simply click go. The response would be seen in the text below.

The reason I would recommend this tool more then the other, is this tool is provided by a community which is more reversed in concepts of application security then any other. These tools are tested and verified by experts. More info [owasp ref](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CAL9000_Project)

**ALTERNATE METHOD**

http://yehg.net/pentest/CAL9000/#httpRequests

its an online version of the tool.

**NOTE ON TRACE**

*Firefox does not currently support the TRACE function (via xmlHttpRequest). CAL9000 gets the TRACE info from a server-side script. Also, a reminder that any request directed at a resource (http://www.blah.com/index.html) is not necessarily going to generate the same response as one directed at a directory (http://www.blah.com/js/), even though they are on the same site.*

Answer (score 1):

Use Python

```
>>> from requests import request
>>> method_list = ['get', 'post', 'trace']
>>> for method in method_list:
...     req = request(method, 'http://example.com')
...     print(method, req.status_code, req.reason)
... 
get 200 OK
post 200 OK
trace 405 Method Not Allowed
>>>
```

As you can see `trace` is not allowed for example.com