# insecure HTTP Methods Enabled -- how to control?

Tags: appsec, webserver, http, apache, http-proxy

Here I am new to insecure HTTP Methods Enabled.

> The server allows HTTP methods that are considered dangerous.  The
>   following methods were enabled: `PUT`,`DELETE`

Software used: Apache-tomcat-6.0.29.

1. How to reproduce the same?
2. How to fix this problem/issue?

Comment: May have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320959/disabling-put-trace-delete-request-in-apache-tomcat-6-0 or for whitelist: http://serverfault.com/questions/662548/disallowing-http-methods-on-tomcat-is-case-sensitive

Comment: how to reproduce this HTTP Methods Enabled or not. @danny

Comment: What do you want to reproduce? Do you want to test the HTTP Methods? Then simply create an HTTP Request (Tools on internet or have a look at the posted questions). Would be great if you show a bit more effort (Improve Quality of your question, make clear what you want). Otherwhise the community will not give you enough attention.

Comment: In case you use (FULL) REST API's, the PUT and DELETE methods should be enabled. It's recommended to only have these method enabled at a specific endpoint such as http://..../api/

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How to reproduce the same?

There are multiple answers on this site for exactly that question. Typing `HTTP method` into the Search box pulls up:

- [How to exploit HTTP Methods](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/how-to-exploit-http-methods)
- [How to identify the HTTP methods supported by a web server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70561/how-to-identify-the-http-methods-supported-by-a-web-server)
- [Testing for HTTP TRACE method](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31659/testing-for-http-trace-method)
- [How can I test that I have correctly disabled unnecessary HTTP
  methods?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45694/how-can-i-test-that-i-have-correctly-disabled-unnecessary-http-methods/45708)

> 2. How to fix this problem issue?

Under Tomcat, you can [disable specific methods via the web.xml configuration file](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/disable-http-methods-in-tomcat.html):

```
 <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name><strong>restricted methods</strong></web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>
  <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
  <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
  <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint />
 </security-constraint>
```

As @Danny points out in the comments, you may want a whitelist rather than a blacklist, and [here's a Tomcat 7 example](https://serverfault.com/a/662594/279074).  Here's an [alternative for Tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8071539/1748148).

That being said, a blacklist is often sufficient for HTTP methods because:

- There's a reasonably static/unchanging list of what's supported,
- Unsupported methods are generally quietly dropped by any competent web server

That said, if the report of Tomcat being case sensitive is true, a whitelist would be the appropriate way to compensate for crappy software.

Comment: Well, from Security point of view he should do "whitelisting" not "blacklisting". Disable everything and only allows "accepted" methods like: http://serverfault.com/questions/662548/disallowing-http-methods-on-tomcat-is-case-sensitive .